# get pending orders price using Amazon MWS API

Tags: api, amazon-mws

I am trying to process the orders from certain Amazon store. But was faced with a problem:

I can not get total price (or total amount) for orders with 'Pending' status. This field is empty. This info can not be retrieved even via OrderItems.

Amazon API docs says:

> Note: When an order is in the Pending state (the order has been placed but payment has not been authorized), the ListOrderItems operation does not return information about pricing, taxes, shipping charges, gift wrapping, or promotions for the order items in the order. After an order leaves the Pending state (this occurs when payment has been authorized) and enters the Unshipped, Partially Shipped, or Shipped state, the ListOrderItems operation returns information about pricing, taxes, shipping charges, gift wrapping, and promotions for the order items in the order.

But I really need it. In addition I saw some apps, which can 'see' OrderAmount for pending orders.

Maybe anyone have already resolved this question? Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `SellerSKU` along with a Amazon price stored in my database to calculate the order value. It is an estimate, though, since the price may have been updated recently (and the order might not reflect the new price) and I cannot calculate the shipping price - neither the price nor the address is known for pending orders.

At least in my usage, I don't see a reason for trying to get the exact amount before the order actually leaves the `Pending` state. Quantities and SKUs are known, so you can reserve stock accordingly which is the only task I actually *need* to know pending orders for.